# Storing download links within MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently building an MVC C# web application that would be selling digital movies. Basically, users would be allowed to login and create an account and add movies to cart. After adding to cart they may proceed with payments. If payments are successful, they will receive a download link for that movie. I would like to find out how I can include this feature with my web application?

Any help will be appreciated as I'm new to this language, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a database to store the real location of the movies in the database and once successful payment has been confirmed, you can generate a link that expires after a certain period of time, you can do this by making an additional entry to the database that specify read permissions for `x` user for `y` amount of time.

Every time the user tries to use the link, you can first see if the user is authenticated, whether their link has expired (by checking the database) and if its not expired, ensure that the user making the request is the user that the download permission was given to, if all those conditions return true, you can proceed to return the file for download directly....

The way you've posed the question leaves out too many variables, leading to too many other questions... what database you'll be using, whether it'll be hosted on the cloud or on dedicated servers... what payment provider you'll be using... etc... as things stand, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Create download action

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    //check payment and other condition
    //if condition not passed return null or redirect user to error view
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.Path($"\\AppData\\{fileName}"));
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

You can read file from database